# Inset border on photos

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a border that sits INSIDE an image. So, there should be a 10px or so margin from the edge of the photo to where the border is.

Examples of what it should look like:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5pBy.jpg

You can see the page with the photos here:  http://blueboxluxe.com/praise/

Anyways, few parts of this is harder to do... 1) the layout is fluid -- the photo size can change. 2) I want the border to show up on all photos -- no matter the size. 3) On the praise page, there's a lot of floats happening; so, things need to work with that correctly.

I've tried playing with box-shadow, but all I get is a border on the outside of the image. Not inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the outline property and specify a negative offset:

```
outline:2px solid red;
outline-offset:-15px;
```

No IE support though!

Answer (score 0):

you can also try a container div

```
<div><img src=""/></div>
```

give div a fixed height and width and overflow hidden.
`div{height:100px;width:100px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid black;`}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a div within the div that contains the image, set it to

```
position:absolute;
margin:2% auto;
left:2%;
width:96%;
border:solid 1px #fff;
```

and then give the element that is containing it:

```
text-align:center;
```

Alternatively, if the image is floating in a much larger div that contains other elements, put it into a parent div set to the size of the image then put the new div that will add the border underneath or above the image; do not put the image into the div that you want to use as a border; the reason I used percentages is because it should then resize depending on the size of the image.

If you play around with the numbers it should work as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the box-shadow property in css3. Use a 1px thick box-shadow with a color would give you that effect on almost all browsers.

Comment: He wants it within the image not around the outside.

Comment: he so you would use negative values...it will create the desired inset effect.

Comment: Interesting, which values would be negative?

Comment: just realized it doesn't work in ie either so the outline solution is currently better because it is only 2 lines whereas box-shadow would be like 5-6 to support all the browsers.